# Overlay shapefile boundaries on geom_tile heat map in R

Tags: r, shapefile, overlay, ggplot2

I have a square matrix which corresponds to a square area of a map.

The values represent the mean value of any centroids in the relevant grid square.

I am visualising this using geom_tile in ggplot.

For example:

```
set.seed(123)
matrix <- matrix(runif(256, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 16, ncol = 16)

library(reshape2)
df <- melt(matrix)
colnames(df) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

I know the GPS coordinates that correspond to the corners of this square (
`x_min`, `x_max`, `y_min`, `y_max`).

I have also got the shapefiles for the relevant area, and can plot these:

```
  p_shapefile <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = lsoa, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(x_min, x_max), 
             ylim = c(y_min, y_max))
```

where

```
> str(lsoa)
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  33755 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ label   : chr  "E92000001E12000003E08000036E02002465E01011905" "E92000001E12000008E07000178E02007116E01035743" "E92000001E12000007E09000029E02000849E01004171" "E92000001E12000008E07000178E02005946E01028571" ...
 $ lsoa21cd: chr  "E01011905" "E01035743" "E01004171" "E01028571" ...
 $ lsoa21nm: chr  "Wakefield 028C" "Oxford 019C" "Sutton 010A" "Oxford 007B" ...
 $ name    : chr  "Wakefield 028C" "Oxford 019C" "Sutton 010A" "Oxford 007B" ...
 $ geometry:sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 33755; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:13, 1:2] 431828 431932 432192 432541 432428 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "label" "lsoa21cd" "lsoa21nm" "name"
```

I want to layer the shape file boundaries over my geom_tile plot. I've tried scaling the coordinates in the `df` to the right area, but can't get it to work.

[image: Current plots and desired plot]

Comment: Convert your matrix to a raster with proper extend (`terra::rast()` function), and the same CRS as in your shapefile, then plot one over another.